# Xcode - Switching View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have implemented the FacebookSDK to allow the user to login, and I have created a new ViewController named "nextViewController" and am not sure how to connect the two once facebook auth was completed. According to the documentation, it should be in this method:

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
```

Within this method, how do I transition to my next view being "nextViewController"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `loginViewFetchedUserInfo` you're on the right track… Use the below code to switch ViewControllers.

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    //use this if you're using storyboard. set storyboard ID to "next"
    nextViewController *nextView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"next"];
    [self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:^{
        }];

   //use this if you're using xib
   //Given that next.xib is the name of your xib file and nextViewController the name of your view controller class.
   nextViewController * nextView = [[nextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"next" bundle:nil];
   [self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:^{
        }];


}
```

Comment: Real quick, I am receiving the following error, "Use of undeclared identifier 'nextview'". Do I need to implement something in my ".h" file like a variable decalration of some sort? Thanks

Comment: I have declared the nextViewController for you in the code. Check if your class name is nextViewController and correct the syntax

Comment: Here is what I have and it is still yelling at me for an undeclared identifier 'nextView'. In story board I have selected the nextViewController and made sure that that class name is showing up as such. Here is what I have:

Comment: - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    homeViewController *nextView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"next"];
    [self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", user.name);
}

Comment: In your code you are using homeViewController instead if nextViewController...

Comment: right right, the actual name of the controller is "homeViewController" and I have made sure that they line up. I only stated "nextViewController" to make it easier to answer the question for me.

Comment: other than that, does everything look correct to you? It is still yelling at me and I am not sure why

Comment: Check you class name in you storyboard if it is "homeViewController" and storyboard id is "next"

Comment: Is there a warning in your code?

Comment: Ty, so yes I made sure that the storyboard's class name is "homeViewController" as well as the id being "next" (without quotes). The only build warning i have is "unsupported configuration, Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier..". Should I be using a segue, if so which one?

Comment: The code I provided will switch the views without segue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59771/discussion-between-user3079072-and-ty).